# Fujitsu Esprimo Q510 (mini PC) as a Ubuntu headless server

Tags: server, hardware

Can you install Ubuntu server on this hardware? Any problems?

Fujitsu Esprimo Q510 (mini PC)
Intel G2020T 2.5GHz

Further question: is the fan loud?

I want to use it as a ubuntu server for mini-projects at home.

Cheers!

Comment: No, this question is an explicit and clearly defined question concerning Esprimo Q510.

Comment: What's the difference from an Ask Ubuntu point of view between the Esprimo Q510 and any other PC? You can try the Ubuntu live session to find out if the hardware works. What you should be curious about is whether that mini PC is durable enough to last for a long time.

Comment: Well, I wanted to be sure it worked with Ubuntu *before* I purchased it. I would have been very happy to find an specific answer like this, then.

Comment: You can't test a product that you don't have, it's true. The Esprimo Q510 got great reviews on Amazon, but maybe it's a lemon anyway. Intel's got a reputation to uphold, so they wouldn't mess with their NUCs.

Answer (score 2):

It worked just fine to install Ubuntu Server on Esprimo Q510. No issues.

I installed Ubuntu Server over DHCP/PXE-boot (dnsmasq).

The Q510 is very quiet. I can't hear any fan noise.

Comment: did you have to modify the BIOS settings beforehand or was it possible to boot straight from an USB key with the Ubuntu installer on it?

Comment: I have a DHCP-server on my home network which serves as a PXE-server as well and has options for installing different Linux OSes. I modified the boot options in the BIOS settings on the Q510 so it could boot over the network. I’ve not tried to boot from the USB, but it should probably work.

Comment: Thanks @UbuntuLover, I'll try that shortly.

Comment: Following up on this, I've purchased a Fujitsu Esprimo Q510 with the Intel i5-4570T CPU @ 2.90GHz 8Gb RAM 512 HDD. Linux Ubuntu 18.04 server installed just fine—hit F12 at start to boot from the USB key with the Ubuntu Server installer and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out is to start a Xubuntu desktop install disk after connecting a Monitor, Mouse and keyboard and possible USB DVD drive.
Insert the CD, (maybe select DVD in BIOS) and select "Try it".

This will boot up the live CD. That does already check parts of your hardware. If you can use the GUI and maybe connect to the network, then you have a very good feel whether or not your box is running the system ok. 
Ubuntu is actually very good to detect hardware and run on most system. I have it running on quite a few low spec and old PCs and use it even with GUI.

The server is using the same kernel and code base, it just does not install the GUI stuff and has a few typical server defaults programs installed. So if the desktop ran ok, but a bit slow the server should be fine. If you got a lot or errors or trouble in booting the live CD you could except a trouble with the server as well.

Also your fans would behave the same.

Once that is OK, I would install the Server CD and activte OpenSSH to get a remote access for headless operation.

Hope it helps